# Beginner Taxicab Distances

Tags: python

I am a beginner Python programmer enrolled in a Python course. The prompt is to essentially calculate the taxicab distance between a series of points in a city, however I am getting silly results. The prompt sets up the city as 26 row, 9 column, using a capital letter and numeric to describe its location. For instance, A1 is the bottom left corner of city. A2 is the bottom row, second column. The function I wrote to calculate the distances seems to work on its own, but once I incorporate it into my main while loop, it throws values that are way too high. The example prompt my teacher gives is as follows:

[image]

I've tried many different statements in the while loop, and I thought I had finally found one that worked using a temporary variable to store the previous location, but it just won't work. The loop is meant to end when the user types 'home' and the distance should be recalculated to find the distance to get home as well.

```
def calculate_distance(p1, p2):
    x1 = ord(p1[0])
    y1 = ord(p1[1])
    x2 = ord(p2[0])
    y2 = ord(p2[1])
    d = abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1)
    return d


def main():
    home = input('Home? ')
    point = input('Next? ')
    distance = calculate_distance(home, point)
    while point != 'home':
        tmp = point
        point = input('Next? ')
        distance += calculate_distance(tmp, point)
    distance += calculate_distance(home, tmp)
    print(distance)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is my code. Don't worry about the extra details on the example prompt, those will be easy once this part works. Also the first two inputs are assumed to never be 'home'. I used the prompt my teacher gave above and got 107.

Comment: You are passing the user's entered `point` value to `calculate_distance()` *before* you are checking whether it is the special value "home".  The `o` and the `e`, in particular, will be seen as being a huge distance away from the digits that an actual point would have in those locations.

Comment: @jasonharper It's intentionally set up that way so the home value can be set. It's assuming the first two inputs will never be 'home'

Comment: @Dennis, I think @jasonharper was actually referring to your use of `calculate_distance()` within the loop, not the use before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One significant issue is that within the while loop, your code executes the statement `distance += calculate_distance(tmp, point)` when `point` has the value 'home'. This will give garbage output from your `calculate_distance()` function (ascii arithmetic subtracting letters from numbers, or vice versa).

Another issue is that the line before you print the result reads:

```
distance += calculate_distance(home, tmp)
```

But the most recent coordinate the user entered before typing 'home' was stored in `point`, not in `tmp`. Try replacing `tmp` with `point` in the above line as shown below:

```
distance += calculate_distance(home, point)
```

A working version correcting the above two issues is:

```
def main():
    home = input('Home? ')
    point = input('Next? ')
    distance = calculate_distance(home, point)
    tmp = point
    point = input('Next? ')
    while point != 'home':
        distance += calculate_distance(tmp, point)
        tmp = point
        point = input('Next? ')
    distance += calculate_distance(tmp, home)
    print(distance)
```

Comment: Hmm, I did that edit and now when I enter the prompt I get 202.

Comment: Sorry, it's a different issue ... editing answer now.

Comment: @Dennis, the larger issue has to do with inadvertently using 'home' as a coordinate.

Comment: Ohhh I see it now!! Thank you so much for your help and apologies for forgetting to explicitly ask a question. Tried to be as concise as possible without losing detail, but ended up forgetting to actually ask a question.